# Call an api from other external spring boot app

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have two different springboot apps. Each has spring security enabled with UsernameAndPasswordAuthentication mechanism and JWT. I have a requirement to call one of the app api from other, but i dont need a user to validate wit username and password since both apps will have different users, each request will be authorized if it Authorization header contains valid JWT token. what i need is if an api called from external application it should check Authorization header has "Basic someAccessToken". Is it even possible to do this kind of implementation.

Comment: Have a URL pattern defined specifically for all app to app communication in app2  and allow anonymous access for that URL pattern to consume rest API of app2 in app1

Comment: Anonymus access in the sense any one can access the url?

Comment: Refer this to understand your options - https://www.baeldung.com/security-none-filters-none-access-permitAll - basically you can disable spring security for application to application by specifying a unique  url pattern and then do any checks manually yourself if you need at all - like a request header only the two apps know about,

Answer (score 0):

It is possible: the calling up sets the JWT token on the http `authorization` header (using the Bearer schema, this is generally accepted practise)

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.add("Authorization", "Bearer " + jwtToken);

MyDto dto = new MyDto();
HttpEntity<MyDto> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(dto, headers);

ResponseEntity resp =
            new RestTemplate().exchange("http://localhost:8080/rest/service",
                    HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, String.class);
```

On the service side obtain the token and validate the access:

```
public ResponseEntity<String> create(@RequestBody MyDto dto, @RequestHeader("authorization") String authorization) throws Exception {

    System.out.println("authorization: " + authorization);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Thats very useful. But in order to get the request headers in service, first i need to get through spring security. So, do i need to permitt all these kind of routes?

Comment: With  http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api") in the security config, deciding which paths require basic auth (ie .authenticated().and().httpBasic();) and which ones dont